# Applying CSS and placeholder text to a rails login form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

```
<% title "Log in" %>

<p>Don't have an account? <%= link_to "Sign up!", signup_path %></p>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :login, "Username or Email Address" %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :login, params[:login] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></p>
<% end %>
```

How can I customise these login fields with CSS and placeholder text? they're not like normal html fields. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the documentation of [FormTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html). Changing you form to following would apply the classes to you labels and fields, then you can style them the way you want.

```
<% title "Log in" %>

<p>Don't have an account? <%= link_to "Sign up!", signup_path %></p>

<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :login, "Username or Email Address", :class => "login-label" %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :login, params[:login], :class => "login-field" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <!-- second parameter is the content to be written inside label parameter, you can also pass nil which will humanize the first parameter -->
    <%= label_tag :password, "Password", :class => "password-label" %><br />

    <!-- second parameter is the value to be populated, you can pass nil if you don't want any -->
    <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, :class => "password-field" %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Log in", :class => "login-button" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Inline styling is not a good idea IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

They do compile into plain-old HTML fields. For instance

```
<%= label_tag :password %>
```

compiles into

```
<label for="password">Password</label>
```

You can pass additional options to add additional parameters to the tag. Example:

```
<%= label_tag :password, "Password", :class => "some_class", :style => "background: green;" %>
```

compiles to

```
<label class="some_class" for="password" style="background: green;">Password</label>
```

The same is true for password_field_tag, text_field_tag, and pretty much any other tag helper.